# Python , Python on M2 Mac, Installation error

Tags: python, macos

can anyone help me whats the problem in it. I get this error again and again "zsh: command not found: python".I was not able to rum my python code. How can I able to run my python Conde on my M2 Macpro 13"?

I tried "python3 --version" and I get "Python 3.11.0"
But when I try "python --version", I gives "zsh: command not found: python"

Comment: Python is installed on your system as the `python3` command.  If you want to also use `python` as the command, make `python` a command alias that points to `python3`.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

'python' command was originally used for Python 2.7 and since there was a major difference in Python 2.7 and Python 3.1, they were used with different commands to avoid other programs / dependencies breaking.

- 'python' -> Python 2.7
- 'python3' -> Python 3

You can set alias for python in .zshrc file

```
echo "alias python='python3'" >> ~/.zshrc
```